# What is the height of overflow over vessel edge?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

[image]

Hello,

Consider a flow (at an x flow rate of incompressible fluid) flowing into a vessel (let's assume it's a round vessel with diameter d). How to calculate the height of overflow,h, over the edge of the vessel?

I know $flowrate_{In}$ = $flowrate_{out}$. At the outlet I don't know the velocity of the flow and the height (to calculate the area)

Comment: Suppose the vessel is empty and you let in N volume units of liquid. What is the height of that liquid in the vessel assuming the vessel is cylindrical?

Comment: @AlvinL Assuming there is no overflowing, you can solve it using ...N = ((pi*d^2)/4)*height. Solve for height.

Comment: The displacement forces the column of liquid to overflow with the height you found from the above.